# Gave bounty to wrong answer - reversing bounty?

Tags: discussion, support

I made a mistake and gave a bounty to another answer instead of the one I selected as best answer. How do I take back the bounty and give it to the correct answer ?

Link - [How do I extract rows from a PDF file into a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688572/how-do-i-extract-rows-from-a-pdf-file-into-a-csv-file/32715737?noredirect=1#comment55174152_32715737)

Comment: You probably cannot, at least not after a certain grace period has expired.

Comment: why the downvotes ? Its like people are looking for a punching bag :)

Comment: Looks like you didn't award it to any answer and the auto award kicked in.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Its been a while. I must have forgotten to. I thought that I had given the award. I want it to go to the right answer. There is no way to create a new bounty.

Comment: @stack1 I would not worry too much about downvotes here - they don't affect your rep

Comment: Last time I awarded a bounty, I got pestered by constant email reminders; before, at, and shortly *after* the expiry time, over a course of several days. You missed all of them? Does SO need to send more?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think it can be done - hence the warning pop-up that states "This cannot be undone" as confirmation

Comment: Is there a work around ? Maybe request the awardee to give it to the correct answer or return my bounty ?

Comment: @stack1 there is no work around and no alternative.  No one, including the awardee can do anything about it.  What's done is done and cannot be undone.  If you really feel that you need to correct this "injustice", then you need to start a 2nd bounty (for 100 rep) and award it to the answer you wanted originally.

Comment: @stack1 correction, you need to start a bounty of 150 since the previous one was for 100, which means you need to earn some additional rep.

Comment: @psubsee2003 200. It needs to be double.

Comment: Yes, from memory, subsequent bounties from the same person on the same question need to be double. That will have the added benefit of rewarding the real person you wanted the bounty awarded to even more than the wrong person. Of course, that's going to cost you some rep, hopefully enough that you'll look more carefully next time :-)

Comment: In my case I was posted one bounty question and I got two answer from my bounty question, but by mistake I gave bounty to the wrong answer.